# Null pointer error in OpenCV working with Xcode

Tags: c, xcode, opencv

I am a student, learning OpenCV with Xcode.

With the help of Googling, I included OpenCV file directories in search paths and added OpenCV frameworks. I included a test image with jpeg or png extension in a project folder, and loaded it in Xcode.

I wrote down the basic OpenCV code, and when I compile it, "null pointer error" keeps following.

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>

int main()
{
    IplImage *img = cvLoadImage("./ex2-4/background.jpeg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

    if ( img == NULL ) {
        printf("Error : null pointer is entered\n");
    }

    cvNamedWindow("Example1", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cvShowImage("Example1", img);
    cvWaitKey(0);

    cvReleaseImage(&img);
    cvDestroyWindow("Example1");

    return 0;
}
```

Error message is shown below:

Error : null pointer is entered
OpenCV Error: Null pointer (NULL array pointer is passed) in cvGetMat, file /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_graphics_opencv/opencv/work/opencv-2.4.10/modules/core/src/array.cpp, line 2382
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_graphics_opencv/opencv/work/opencv-2.4.10/modules/core/src/array.cpp:2382: error: (-27) NULL array pointer is passed in function cvGetMat

Program ended with exit code: 9

PS: However, it works in Visual Studio very well, but I would like to run on Xcode.

Comment: Change path to an absolute one and see if it happen again.

Comment: I used both image name and directories included, but both won't work.

Comment: Absolute path won't work either. Same error message is on.

Comment: @JimYang I changed absolute path and it finally works! Thank you so much:)

Comment: you should figure out what is the 'Working directory' when debugging with XCode, and absolute path is not always a proper solution.

Comment: How to find the 'working directory'? I think only absolute path is working out, only in Mac OS

Comment: I'm not familiar with XCode :(.

Comment: Thanks anyway, it helped a lot =)

Comment: you *must not* use the deprecated c-api any more. please switch to the c++ one

Answer (score 0):

Even your question is answered, but the following code snippet is a source of danger:

```
if ( img == NULL ) {
        printf("Error : null pointer is entered\n");
    }
```

You know that `img` is `NULL` and continue the execution. In such cases the execution should be terminated,

```
if ( img == NULL ) {
        printf("Error : null pointer is entered\n");
        return -1;
    }
```